# Magento . 2.3.5-p1: third party payment methods not displaying in Backend: Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment methods

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods

**I want to use / install 3rd party payment methods on the Magento v 2.3.5-p1.**

I am aware that in this version the payment methods that were previously included, have been removed: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-5-open-source.html

When I was using the Magento version 2.3.1 I would use some external/3rd party payment methods installed via composer, namely:

```
 composer require mercadopago/magento2-plugin:2
```

and

```
composer require moip/magento2
```

In previous Magento 2.3.x versions, I would successfully install either/both modules above, and they would display (in the backend) as payment method options under **Backend:  Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment methods.**

However, I have installed both modules via composer on the versions 2.3.5-p1, and although they were successfully installed via composer (ran bin upgrade, cache:cache, cache: flush and static-content:Deploy), neither display on the Payment method area (image below).

**Do I need to do something 'extra' on this Magento version for 3rd party payment methods/modules to display in the backend configuration area?**

**To confirm: I am able to see the module installed in the front-end when I go to the checkout and try to place an order. The issue is not being able to see and configure them in the backend.**

[image]

Comment: you run all commands and apply permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, after a few hours spent on forums I found out that this is a **specific bug on the Magento v 2.3.5-p1** version: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28132

There seems to be an **issue with the integrated Klarna module** (which comes pre-installed with this version). When disabling Klarna the payment methods are loaded as normal.

I have therefore ran:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Klarna_Kp Klarna_Ordermanagement Klarna_Core
```

Result:

```
The following modules have been disabled:
- Klarna_Core
- Klarna_Ordermanagement
- Klarna_Kp
```

Then I have ran the following:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Logged out my admin, logged in again and now I can see all the payment methods on **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment methods**.
[image: Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment methods]